# Bootstrap popover on a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I'm trying to open a popover on a form, if the first option ("Nothing selected") is selected, when clicking "Next" on a wizard.
I'm using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) and [Bootstrap Wizard](http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/).

I've already gotten a popover to work, but not in the way I need.
I want the popover on the `<a>` tag, but when the Next button is clicked, not when I click the "Test" button.

I hope I'm being clear.

Here's what I've tried so far:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" id="warning" title="Hello" data-content="Bye!">Test</a>
    <select class="form-control input-lg" id="some_id">
        <option value="0">Nothing selected</option>
    </select>
    <br>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
        onNext: function (tab, navigation, index) {
            $("#warning").popover({
            container: "body"
            })
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some errors in your javascript and you weren't initializing the popover: `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();`

The following works

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" id="warning" title="Hello" data-content="Bye!">Test</a>
    <select class="form-control input-lg" id="some_id">
        <option value="0">Nothing selected</option>
    </select>
    <br>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/1.2/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
        onNext: function (tab, navigation, index) {
            $("#warning").popover({
                container: "body"
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Edit: added fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timgavin/4rwzsmgc/

Comment: It still doesn't work, nothing happens when clicking the "Next" button. I've made all the changes you suggested.

Comment: it works. I've updated my answer with a fiddle. If it's not working on your end something else could be conflicting with it, or you overlooked something.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answers. The popover works, just not as I intend it to. It's working when you click on the `<a>` tag, but not when clicking 'next' on the wizard, which is the purpose of my question.
Thanks anyway.